# How can I connect a Quectel module to an STM32 board via USB and manage the com_port?

Tags: usb, stm32, lte, quectel, usb-hostcontroller

i have a quectel module and i want connect this module to stm32f4 board with the usb port
i can connect two stm32 board togheter and send or receive data between them
but when i connect this module to stm32 board
Nothing happens
i think this problem is related to  module com_port
becase when i connect module to computer
computer show the 3 port
how can manage stm32 board which port to open ?
i config stm32 board on the usb host.

i think this problem is related to  module com_port
becase when i connect module to computer
computer show the 3 port
how can manage stm32 board which port to open ?
i config stm32 board on the usb host.